# Embedding a plot inside a pairs plot space image in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph

I have a pairs plot and a barplot made with ggplot2. I'm wondering if I can embed my barplot inside the space of my pairs plot.
It would look something like this:

[image]

Here is the code for both plots:

```
#pairs plot

    pairs(pca$eigenvect[,1:4], labels = lbls, col=tab$pop, 
                lower.panel = NULL)

#barplot

    ggplot(head_eigen, aes(x=pcindex, y = varexp), group=1) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=0.6, fill="steelblue") +
      theme_minimal() +
      geom_point(color="darkblue")+
      geom_text(aes(label=varexp), vjust=-0.3, size=3.5)+
      geom_line(color="darkblue" ,group=1)+
      ylim(0,5)+
      ylab("Explained variance (%)") + xlab("Principle Component Number")
```

I've tried `ggplot` function `annotation_custom` and also `cowplot` function `ggdraw` but any of them seem to work because pairs is not really a singe plot.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Random data:

```
pca = data.frame(e1=sort(rnorm(100, 0, 1)),e2=sort(rnorm(100, 0, 1)),e3=sort(rnorm(100, 0, 1)),e4=sort(rnorm(100, 0, 1)))
```

I had some trouble storing a `pairs()` plot as a variable, but managed to do it using `%<a-%` from the `pryr` library:

```
library(pryr)
library(grid)
p1 %<a-% pairs(pca[,1:4],lower.panel = NULL)
p2 = ggplot(pca, aes(x=e1,y=e2)) + geom_point()
vp <- viewport(width = 0.4, height = 0.4, x = 0.25, y = 0.3)
print(p1)
print(p2, vp=vp)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked perfectly! 
In case other people have the same issue, notice that viewport function belongs to the grid package that needs to be on.